# Coreplot build failed issue in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I am facing the following issue while building the application with core plot library.
It was working before 2 days. But it suddenly stopped running.

```
libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CPTDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
      -[GraphView generateLayout] in GraphView.o
  "_CPTDecimalFromInt", referenced from:
      -[GraphView generateLayout] in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTAxisLabel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTBarPlot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTConstraints", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTFill", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GraphView in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableLineStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableTextStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPlotRange", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GraphView.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GraphView in GraphView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I think you will find a solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20266141/4177109

Comment: @Ckouta Thank you for your quick reply. I referred that link, it not solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add new core plot library framework to your project. Remove the old library. These are the steps to follow

1. Download the core plot library.
2. open the xcode CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj
3. Go to project and click on build
4. Now go to core plot framework folder in your mac. You can see build folder in that.
5. Now open the terminal and give your core plot path
6. cd CorePlot_1.4/Source/build/
7. Type  lipo -create ./Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a ./Debug-iphonesimulator/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a -output core_plot_all.a
8. New library created and now add this library and core headers to your project.
9. Now build your project.

After that add -ObjC to other linker flags